# How i can duplicate a record with your dependents in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my use case I need to create an endpoint that duplicates a record and its dependents by copying the data from the current record to a new record creating new primary keys.

***Current response:*** *Original record*

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Grandparent One",
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Parent One",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Child One"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Child Two"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

***Expected response:***  *Original record and Duplicate record*

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Grandparent One",
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Parent One",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Child One"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Child Two"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Grandparent One Copy",
        "parents": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Parent One",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Child One"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Child Two"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do the  implementation this endpoint in the `GrandparentController`?

```
@PostMapping("{id}/duplicate")
    public ResponseEntity<Grandparent> duplicate(@NonNull @PathVariable long id) {
        //How to implement this endpoint?

        return null;
    }
```

My classes:

**MODELS**

***Grandparent***

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "grandparents")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Grandparent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

***Parent***

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "parents")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandparent_id", nullable = false
            , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_parents_grandparent1"))
    private Grandparent grandparent;
    private String name;

}
```

***Children***

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "children")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Children {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false
            , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_children_parent1"))
    private Parent parent;
    private String name;

}
```

**DTOs**

***GrandparentPost***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GrandparentPost {

    private String name;

}
```

***ParentPost***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentPost {

    private Grandparent grandparent;
    private String name;

}
```

***ChildrenPost***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChildrenPost {

    private Parent parent;
    private String name;

}
```

***GrandparentResponseDto***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GrandparentResponseDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<ParentResponseDto> parents;

    public GrandparentResponseDto(Grandparent grandparent) {
        this.id = grandparent.getId();
        this.name = grandparent.getName();
    }
}
```

***ParentResponseDto***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentResponseDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<ChildrenResponseDto> children;

    public ParentResponseDto(Parent parent) {
        this.id = parent.getId();
        this.name = parent.getName();
    }
}
```

***ChildrenResponseDto***

```
package com.example.demo.dto;

import com.example.demo.model.Children;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChildrenResponseDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public ChildrenResponseDto(Children children) {
        this.id = children.getId();
        this.name = children.getName();
    }
}
```

**MAPPERS**

***GrandparentMapper***

```
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.dto.GrandparentPost;
import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class GrandparentMapper {

    public static final GrandparentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(GrandparentMapper.class);

    public abstract Grandparent toGrandparent(GrandparentPost grandparentPost);

}
```

***ParentMapper***

```
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.dto.ParentPost;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class ParentMapper {

    public static final ParentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ParentMapper.class);

    public abstract Parent toParent(ParentPost parentPost);

}
```

***ChildrenMapper***

```
package com.example.demo.mapper;

import com.example.demo.dto.ChildrenPost;
import com.example.demo.model.Children;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class ChildrenMapper {

    public static final ChildrenMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildrenMapper.class);

    public abstract Children toChildren(ChildrenPost childrenPost);

}
```

**REPOSITORIES**

***GrandparentRep***

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface GrandparentRep extends JpaRepository<Grandparent, Long> {
}
```

***ParentRep***

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface ParentRep extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    List<Parent> findByGrandparent_Id(long grandparent);

}
```

***ChildrenRep***

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Children;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface ChildrenRep extends JpaRepository<Children, Long> {

    List<Children> findByParent_Id(long parent);
}
```

**SERVICES**

***GrandparentService***

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.GrandparentPost;
import com.example.demo.mapper.GrandparentMapper;
import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import com.example.demo.repository.GrandparentRep;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GrandparentService {

    private final GrandparentRep grandparentRep;

    public List<Grandparent> findAll() {
        return grandparentRep.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Grandparent> findById(long id) {
        return grandparentRep.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Grandparent save(GrandparentPost grandparentPost) {
        return grandparentRep.save(GrandparentMapper.INSTANCE.toGrandparent(grandparentPost));
    }

}
```

***ParentService***

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.ParentPost;
import com.example.demo.mapper.ParentMapper;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import com.example.demo.repository.ParentRep;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentService {

    private final ParentRep parentRep;

    public List<Parent> findBy(long grandparent) {
        return parentRep.findByGrandparent_Id(grandparent);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Parent save(ParentPost parentPost) {
        return parentRep.save(ParentMapper.INSTANCE.toParent(parentPost));
    }

}
```

***ChildrenService***

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.dto.ChildrenPost;
import com.example.demo.mapper.ChildrenMapper;
import com.example.demo.model.Children;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import com.example.demo.repository.ChildrenRep;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChildrenService {

    private final ChildrenRep childrenRep;

    public List<Children> findBy(long parent) {
        return childrenRep.findByParent_Id(parent);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Children save(ChildrenPost childrenPost) {
        return childrenRep.save(ChildrenMapper.INSTANCE.toChildren(childrenPost));
    }

}
```

**CONTROLLERS**

***GrandparentController***

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.dto.ChildrenResponseDto;
import com.example.demo.dto.GrandparentPost;
import com.example.demo.dto.GrandparentResponseDto;
import com.example.demo.dto.ParentResponseDto;
import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import com.example.demo.service.ChildrenService;
import com.example.demo.service.GrandparentService;
import com.example.demo.service.ParentService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/grandparents")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GrandparentController {

    private final GrandparentService grandparentService;
    private final ParentService parentService;
    private final ChildrenService childrenService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Grandparent>> findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(grandparentService.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Grandparent>> findById(@NonNull @PathVariable long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(grandparentService.findById(id));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/stats")
    public ResponseEntity<List<GrandparentResponseDto>> findByStats (@NonNull @PathVariable long id) {
        var grandparentStatsDto = grandparentService.findById(id)
                .stream()
                .map(GrandparentResponseDto::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //List parents
        grandparentStatsDto.forEach(grandparentStatsList -> {
            List<ParentResponseDto> parentResponseDto = parentService
                    .findBy(grandparentStatsList.getId())
                    .stream().map(ParentResponseDto::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            //List children
            parentResponseDto.forEach(parentStatsList -> {
                List<ChildrenResponseDto> childrenResponseDto = childrenService
                        .findBy(parentStatsList.getId())
                        .stream().map(ChildrenResponseDto::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                parentStatsList.setChildren(childrenResponseDto);
            });
            grandparentStatsList.setParents(parentResponseDto);
        });
        return ResponseEntity.ok(grandparentStatsDto);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Grandparent> save(@NonNull @Valid @RequestBody GrandparentPost grandparentPost) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(grandparentService.save(grandparentPost), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("{id}/duplicate")
    public ResponseEntity<Grandparent> duplicate(@NonNull @PathVariable long id) {
        //How to implement this endpoint?

        return null;
    }


}
```

***ParentController***

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.dto.ParentPost;
import com.example.demo.model.Grandparent;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import com.example.demo.service.ParentService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/grandparents/{grandparent}/parents")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParentController {

    private final ParentService parentService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Parent>> findBy(@PathVariable long grandparent) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(parentService.findBy(grandparent));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Parent> save(@NonNull @Valid @RequestBody ParentPost parentPost
            , @NonNull @PathVariable long grandparent) {
        parentPost.setGrandparent(new Grandparent(grandparent, null));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(parentService.save(parentPost), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


}
```

***ChildrenController***

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.dto.ChildrenPost;
import com.example.demo.model.Children;
import com.example.demo.model.Parent;
import com.example.demo.service.ChildrenService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/grandparents/{grandparent}/parents/{parent}/children")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChildrenController {

    private final ChildrenService childrenService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Children>> findBy(@PathVariable long grandparent) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(childrenService.findBy(grandparent));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Children> save(@NonNull @Valid @RequestBody ChildrenPost childrenPost
            , @NonNull @PathVariable long parent) {
        childrenPost.setParent(new Parent(parent, null, null));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(childrenService.save(childrenPost), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
@PostMapping("{id}/duplicate")
    public ResponseEntity<Grandparent> duplicate(@NonNull @PathVariable long id) {

        var originGrandparent = grandparentService.findById(id);
        var originParentList = parentService.findBy(originGrandparent.get().getId());
        var originChildrenList = new ArrayList<Children>();

        originParentList.forEach(originParent -> {
            List<Children> originChildren = childrenService.findBy(originParent.getId());
            originChildrenList.addAll(originChildren);
        });

        var newGrandparent = new GrandparentPost();
        newGrandparent.setName(originGrandparent.get().getName() + " copy");
        var savedGrandparent = grandparentService.save(newGrandparent);

        var newParent = new ParentPost();
        var savedParentList = new ArrayList<Parent>();

        originParentList.forEach(originParent -> {
            newParent.setGrandparent(new Grandparent(savedGrandparent.getId(), null));
            newParent.setName(originParent.getName());
            var savedParent = parentService.save(newParent);
            savedParentList.add(savedParent);
            originChildrenList.forEach(origenChild -> {
                if (Objects.equals(origenChild.getParent().getId(), originParent.getId())) {
                    var newChild = new ChildrenPost();
                    newChild.setParent(savedParent);
                    newChild.setName(origenChild.getName());
                    childrenService.save(newChild);
                }
            });
        });

        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedGrandparent);
    }
```

If anyone knows a way to improve this code, feel free to share.